# Start auto download

Tags: android, google-play

I have multiple apps in the market. Consider that app A is already installed in phone. On some user action in app A i want app B (published in market) to be downloaded.
 If i use below code, it will open details page instead of starting download.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=my.app.package"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there is any way so that app B directly starts downloading?

Comment: You shouldn't download anything without user's consent.

Comment: I want user to view directly app permission screen.. (that means taking users' consent)

Comment: Then you should specify it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't functionality like this built in to Android market intent: [see documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent). So the only way is to direct user to details page and he/she has to tap the download button hem/her self.